# Clojure tools namespace does not seem to work

Tags: clojure

If I try to use `clojure.tools.namespace`:

```
user> (require 'clojure.tools.namespace.repl)
```

I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundException Could not locate clojure/tools/namespace/repl__init.class or clojure/tools/namespace/repl.clj on classpath.  clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:456)
  Show: Clojure Java REPL Tooling Duplicates All  (13 frames hidden)

1. Unhandled java.io.FileNotFoundException
   Could not locate clojure/tools/namespace/repl__init.class or
   clojure/tools/namespace/repl.clj on classpath.

                   RT.java:  456  clojure.lang.RT/load
                   RT.java:  419  clojure.lang.RT/load
                  core.clj: 5893  clojure.core/load/fn
                  core.clj: 5892  clojure.core/load
                  core.clj: 5876  clojure.core/load
               RestFn.java:  408  clojure.lang.RestFn/invoke
                  core.clj: 5697  clojure.core/load-one
                  core.clj: 5692  clojure.core/load-one
                  core.clj: 5737  clojure.core/load-lib/fn
                  core.clj: 5736  clojure.core/load-lib
                  core.clj: 5717  clojure.core/load-lib
               RestFn.java:  142  clojure.lang.RestFn/applyTo
                  core.clj:  648  clojure.core/apply
                  core.clj: 5774  clojure.core/load-libs
                  core.clj: 5758  clojure.core/load-libs
               RestFn.java:  137  clojure.lang.RestFn/applyTo
                  core.clj:  648  clojure.core/apply
                  core.clj: 5796  clojure.core/require
                  core.clj: 5796  clojure.core/require
               RestFn.java:  408  clojure.lang.RestFn/invoke
                      REPL:   45  user/eval10185
                      REPL:   45  user/eval10185
             Compiler.java: 6927  clojure.lang.Compiler/eval
             Compiler.java: 6890  clojure.lang.Compiler/eval
                  core.clj: 3105  clojure.core/eval
                  core.clj: 3101  clojure.core/eval
                  main.clj:  240  clojure.main/repl/read-eval-print/fn
                  main.clj:  240  clojure.main/repl/read-eval-print
                  main.clj:  258  clojure.main/repl/fn
                  main.clj:  258  clojure.main/repl
                  main.clj:  174  clojure.main/repl
               RestFn.java: 1523  clojure.lang.RestFn/invoke
    interruptible_eval.clj:   87  clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate/fn
                  AFn.java:  152  clojure.lang.AFn/applyToHelper
                  AFn.java:  144  clojure.lang.AFn/applyTo
                  core.clj:  646  clojure.core/apply
                  core.clj: 1881  clojure.core/with-bindings*
                  core.clj: 1881  clojure.core/with-bindings*
               RestFn.java:  425  clojure.lang.RestFn/invoke
    interruptible_eval.clj:   85  clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate
    interruptible_eval.clj:   55  clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate
    interruptible_eval.clj:  222  clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/interruptible-eval/fn/fn
    interruptible_eval.clj:  190  clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/run-next/fn
                  AFn.java:   22  clojure.lang.AFn/run
   ThreadPoolExecutor.java: 1142  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor/runWorker
   ThreadPoolExecutor.java:  617  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker/run
               Thread.java:  745  java.lang.Thread/run
```

My `profiles.clj` looks like this:

```
{:repl {:plugins [
                [cider/cider-nrepl "0.12.0"]
                [org.clojure/tools.namespace "0.2.11"]
             ]}}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`clojure.tools.namespace` is a dependency, not a plugin, so it needs to go under the `:dependencies` key in your project.clj.